# Using filterByExpr function of edgeR package for filtering metagenomic count data(otu table)

Tags: metadata

[OTU table contains around 930 samples and 18783 OTU id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZW02c.png)
I am trying to filter my count data using filterByExpr in edgeR package and my file is in csv format. I can read my file and then creating DGEList object and in using the filterByExpr function I am having my difficulty.

[This is the code - I am trying to implement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BJAA.png)
Warning message:
In filterByExpr.DGEList(dge, cutoff = 10, type = "counts") :
All samples appear to belong to the same group.
And it produces null value after filtering, I know there is something that I don't know properly.
My OTU table contains number of reads per sample per OTU and I should filter out the OTUs with zeros in majority of the samples and then download the filtered file.
As I am new to R programming, Can anyone please help me in writing the code for this problem.
Thanking in Advance.